# Quantum walk: transition matrix, negative or positive sign in the exponent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Why is it that in some papers the transition matrix of a continuous-time quantum walk is defined as $\exp(itH)$ and in other papers as $\exp(-itH)$?

Comment: $H$ is Hermitian and both $itH$ and $-itH$ are anti-Hermitian. Both $\exp(itH)$ and $\exp(-itH)$ are unitary. QM has no arrow of time. Nonetheless : do you have a reference where they use the plus sign? See also [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197241/schrodingers-equation-with-negative-sign).

Comment: A link is for example: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~cgodsil/quagmire/QuantumWalks/pdfs/GrfSpc3.pdf  (p. 3)

Answer (score 0):

Because the only thing which matters about $i$ is that $i^2=1$. You can always change $i$ to $-i$ as long as you do it consistently. While the convention is to use $e^{-iHt}$ for time evolution, nothing bad will happen if you take the $+$ sign.