# What's the reason for the minus sign in energy operator and momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, energy, operators, conventions

We have learned the following fundamental correspondence relations from basic quantum mechanics:
$$E\rightarrow i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \tag{1}$$ 
$$\vec{p}\rightarrow-i\hbar \nabla \tag{2}$$

My question is why we take a minus sign in formula $(2)$? I mean we should not take the minus sign from the viewpoint of space-time symmetry.  Is there any relationship with special relativity? If we don't take the minus sign in the replacement for momentum, what will happen in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9557/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90732/2451 and links therein.

Comment: To be sure, $i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is not the energy *operator*