# Does Schroedinger equation depend on the sign of Poisson bracket?

Tags: operators, schroedinger-equation, conventions, commutator, poisson-brackets

Let's consider Poisson bracket

$$\left\{ A,B\right\} =\alpha_{p} \left( 
\frac{\partial A}{\partial p_{k}}\frac{\partial B}{\partial q^{k}}-\frac{%
\partial A}{\partial q^{k}}\frac{\partial B}{\partial p_{k}}\right) \tag{1}$$

where $\alpha _{p}=\pm 1;$ then

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{1}{%
\alpha_{p}}\left\{ H,A\right\} \tag{2}$$
we know relation between Poisson bracket and commutator

$$\left\{ \hat{O}_{A},\hat{O}_{B}\right\} =i \alpha_{c}\left[
\hat{O}_{A},\hat{O}_{B}\right] \tag{3}$$

then Heisenberg equation

$$\frac{d\hat{A}}{dt}=\frac{i \alpha_{c}%
}{\alpha_{p} }\left[ \hat{H},\hat{A}\right] \tag{4}$$

for momentum and coordinate

$$\frac{d\hat{p}}{dt}=\frac{i \alpha_{c}}{\alpha_{p} }\left[ \hat{H},\hat{p}\right] \qquad\text{and} \qquad\frac{d\hat{q}}{dt}=\frac{i \alpha_{c}}{\alpha_{p} }\left[ \hat{H},\hat{q}%
\right] \tag{5}$$

finally we get

$$\frac{i \alpha_{c}}{\alpha_{p} }\frac{\partial \psi 
}{\partial t}=H\psi\tag{6} $$

so there are two independent parameters $\alpha_{c}$ and $\alpha_{p} $ I can choose $\alpha_{c}=1$ and $\alpha_{p}=-1$.

Is that computation correct?

Comment: $\left\{ \hat{O}_{A},\hat{O}_{B}\right\} =i\alpha_p\left[
\hat{O}_{A},\hat{O}_{B}\right]$.

Comment: I edited my question. Now, there are two independent parameters

Answer (score 3):

1. With the standard [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation)
   $$[\hat{q},\hat{p}]~=~i\hbar{\bf 1},  \tag{A}$$
   and with OP's convention (1) for the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) $$\{p,q\}_{PB}~=~\alpha_p,\tag{B}$$
   the operator $\leftrightarrow$ function correspondence reads
   $$ [\hat{f},\hat{g}]\quad\longleftrightarrow\quad\frac{\hbar}{i\alpha_p}\{f,g\}_{PB} +{\cal  O}(\hbar^2) .\tag{C}$$ 
   Note that the traditional physics convention is $\alpha_p=-1$. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. Now let's address OP's title question. The [time-dependent Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) (TDSE)
   $$ i\hbar \frac{d |\psi \rangle}{d t}~=~\hat{H}|\psi \rangle,   \tag{D}$$ 
   and the [Heisenberg equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture)
   $$ \frac{d\hat{f}}{dt}~=~\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{H},\hat{f}] + \frac{\partial \hat{f}}{\partial t},   \tag{E}$$ 
   are independent of the Poisson bracket convention (1);
   while [Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics)'s/[Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian))'s equation
   $$ \frac{df}{dt}~=~\frac{1}{\alpha_p}\{H,f\}_{PB} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t},  \tag{F}$$ 
   does depend on the Poisson bracket convention (1).
3. For discussions of non-standard sign conventions in the TDSE, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90732/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9557/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Comment: you write there same parameter $\alpha_{p}$ but it could be any free parameter. see my edited answer. There is second parameter $\alpha_{c}$ . but you get $\alpha_{p}=\alpha_{c}$ why?

Comment: @Qmechanic A slight generalisation: If you define $[A,B]=\alpha_c(AB-BA)$, then the Heisenberg equation depends on $\alpha_c$. Moreover, the relation between $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ and $[\cdot,\cdot]$ becomes $\alpha_p\{\cdot,\cdot\}=\alpha_c[\cdot,\cdot]$. Finally, the Sch. equation is both independent of $\alpha_p$ and $\alpha_c$. This $\alpha_c$ is **not** the same as in the OP, but I believe this is what they had in mind.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Good point. That would bring the conventional choices in the definitions of $[\cdot,\cdot]$ and $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{PB}$ on equal footing.

Comment: Your derivation is based on that fact that $[\hat{q},\hat{p}]~=~i\hbar{\bf 1}.  \tag{A}$  But do you have any argument why it can't be $[\hat{q},\hat{p}]~= - ~i\hbar{\bf 1}?  \tag{A}$

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: The sign is not physical and I just can take $[\hat{q},\hat{p}]~= - ~i\hbar{\bf 1}$  But I think, in this case there shuould be some changes in Feynman-Stueckelberg interpretation

Answer (score 2):

Because you add a sign to the Poisson brackets, you should do the same to the commutator for the relation

$$\left\{\hat{O}_{A},\hat{O}_{B}\right\}\leftrightarrow i\left[\hat{O}_{A},\hat{O}_{B}\right]$$

to still hold. Thus you just define the Poisson brackets/commutator differently, keeping the explicit equations the same. There is no point of doing this.

**EDIT 1:** The time evolution of a quantity in analytical mechanics is unique

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\left\{A,H\right\}$$

with the regular definition of the Poisson brackets. Also Ehrenfest's theorem is unique

$$\frac{d\left<\hat{A}\right>}{dt}=\frac{1}{i\hbar}\left<\left[\hat{A},\hat{H}\right]\right>$$

with the regular definition of the commutator. This leads us to the usual correspondence

$$\left\{A,B\right\}\leftrightarrow\frac{1}{i\hbar}\left[\hat{A},\hat{B}\right]$$

If for some reason you want to change the usual definitions and write

$$\left\{A,B\right\}_{\rm OP}=\alpha_{\rm PB}\left\{A,B\right\}$$

$$\left[\hat{A},\hat{B}\right]_{\rm OP}=\alpha_{\rm C}\left[\hat{A},\hat{B}\right]$$

then all the above equations change accordingly, but that's only because you defined something differently. It is only a cosmetic change.

Comment: I don't think so. Sign of commutator is absolutely independent from sign of Poisson bracket

Comment: So you should change the relation instead, as @AccidentalFourierTransform already stated in the comment. You have to do either one of the two. QM and Analytical Mechanics are independent, and this is just a correspondence between the two.