# Sign of the momentum operator in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, definition, conventions

What is the physical reason or concept underlying the minus sign in the definition of the momentum operator in QM:

$$\hat{p}_i = -i \hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}~? $$

Comment: Just found the reason in the following old post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9557/

Comment: voted to close since the asker has already helpfully located the duplicate question